# Is there an efficient way to generate multinomial random variables in parallel?

Tags: python, numpy, random, multinomial

numpy.random has the following function to generate multinomial random samples.

```
multinomial(n, p, size)
```

But I wonder if there is an **efficient** way to generate multinomial samples for different parameters n and p. For example,

```
n = np.array([[10],
             [20]])
p = np.array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.7],
             [0.4, 0.4, 0.2]])
```

and even for higher dimension n and p like these:

```
n = np.array([[[10],
        [20]],
       [[10],
        [20]]])
p = np.array([[[0.1, 0.2, 0.7],
        [0.1, 0.2, 0.7]],
       [[0.3, 0.2, 0.5],
        [0.4, 0.1, 0.5]]])
```

I know for the univariate random variable, we can do this kind of things, but don't know how to do it for multinomial in python.

Comment: there is a function for multiple `n`s, but for multiple `n` and `pas, you probably have to multiprocess it (assuming you do not want loops)

Comment: Could you show the output you'd expect from the examples you give? I interpret them as suggesting an output with varying row lengths, which of course is impossible if the output is a single array, as it must be in this case.

Comment: The output of the example would be something like this `array([[[1, 2, 7],
        [2, 4, 14]],
       [[3, 2, 5],
        [8, 2, 10]]])`

Comment: Well, new RNG subsystem in numpy could deal with multiple n, rng.multinomial([[10], [20]], [1/6.]*6, size=(2, 2)) will work, but rng.multinomial([[10], [20]], [[1/6.]*6,[1/5.]*5], size=(2, 2)) won't

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. Thank you for pointing that out. For univariate sampling, we can draw samples from a distribution with different parameters at the same time, such as gamma. I just wonder if there is a way to do that for multinomial.